# How to listen for canGoBack() and canGoForward()?

Tags: android, android-webview

I know I can query if a `WebView` widget can go back or forward using the `canGoBack()` and `canGoForward()` methods. But I want to enable (or disable) toolbar buttons depending on whether the `WebView` can go back or forward and I don't want to poll `canGoBack()` and `canGoForward()` all the time so I'd need something like a listener that is called whenever the state of `canGoBack()` or `canGoForward()` changes.

Is something like that available? I fail to find anything like that in the `WebView` docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I know there is no such listener, but what we can do is

```
setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (view.canGoBack()) {
                //enable back button
            } else {
                //disable back button
            }
            if (view.canGoForward() {
                //enable forward button
            } else {
                //disable forward button
            }
        } 
});
```